# Django Web Application Design Guidance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am looking for some advice before I start on a new project.

I am creating a Web Application using Django 1.10.  I have experience with Django and creating general "content-based" websites with it.  However, since this project is going to be a web-based application, I plan on doing more "complex" things than just rendering HTML templates and doing some basic CRUD operations.  When I say "complex" things, the most specific example I can give at this point is to leverage more asynchronous requests so my web-application can remain responsive to the user and provide that "real-time" experience that comes with an application that might be installed on their local machine or whatever.  Plus, since this is a web-application and not just a website, the project is definitely going to be more data-driven which could potentially mean requesting large amounts of data that would be best served in say a paginated manner, etc.

So, my though was this.....Since I am familiar with Django and have read such good things about the Django REST Framework, I could create a RESTful API to perform all of my CRUD operations and basically interface with my web application's core database.

At that point, I could essentially have two "layers": (1) A presentation layer that will render my web-application's pages and (2) an application layer that will do all my backend CRUD operations.  Since the two are separated, I will also get the added benefit of being able to leverage the API from other avenues (other than my Django web-app) if that is ever required down the road.

I guess my first question is whether or not this makes sense and if so, thoughts on the best way to implement it.  I believe I have two options.

1. Create a single Django project and include the API as a separate application.  This seems like it would work fine but it would couple my API with my presentation since they would both be hosted by the same server.  Which...if the only "consumer" of the API is my one Django site, then this may not be an issue in the near term but could cause problems later on.
2. Separate the two into two distinct Django projects.  This offers the most flexibility and is probably the best answer, I think.

There may be other options as well.  At the end of the day, I am looking for some advice/guidance from those who have done this before and what other things I should consider before starting on this effort.

Comment: I would suggest making a Django REST Framework to build an API and doing the front-end with something like ReactJS or Angular. If you need to have websockets then you can add Django-Channels. The front-end could be static files and a separate project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically I would not recommend the way number 2. This is because you really fast will start to struggle with issues like that: where to store models? Project A, Project B, Both?? Also I am almost sure that you will have other code that can be shared between both of the django projects.

Worth to note here that in two separate django projects - you will have troubles with synchronization of the migrations (just consider simultaneously change of the models in both projects). Personally - I've never was able to solve this in some nice, acceptable way.

Maybe I will share with you my personal experience - hope this will be helpful.

1. First is that if your are making a big application - consider resignation from django templates - use some modern js framework for frontend: react, angular; and make a separate project for fontend. This is tricky because you need to have right competences in the team. If this is not possible - well do separate django app for front.
2. Use DRF - you can create `rest` app inside your project and use all of the models defined elsewhere - it will provide you simple CRUD out of the box and with some work it can be really powerful. If you will be able to create front in modern js framework - this REST can be also used to feed data to the front. And also any other client you can imagine. This basically shift the amount of work needed to be done in the backend (only REST instead of REST + templates and rendering) to the frontend.
3. Asynchronous tasks. Well nothing new here - use celery. Define your tasks inside application; make sure that you have correct number of workers. And let the `magic` begin.
4. As for real-time experience, you may consider using django-channels: https://github.com/django/channels/ It is nice way to handle websocket connections.

Things to consideration:

In big application usually you will end up with something like this:
`myapp.com -> point to frontend`; `api.myapp.com -> point to the api`
You should make a clear separation in the code between this two. In the case when your front is js-based - this is not a problem, but rest + rendering it is important to be able to run `only-api-node` and `only-rendering-node`. It's hard to say which one of them will be used more heavily.

So basically you can end up with something like this:

```
core
    models
        users.py
my_app_frontend
    users
        views.py
        forms.py
        tasks.py
        urls.py
my_app_rest
    users
        serializers.py
        views.py
        signals.py
        urls.py
my_app
    settings.py
    rest_settings.py
    manage.py
    wsgi.py
    rest_wsgi.py
    urls.py
    rest_urls.py
```

This have some advantages that I like:

1. Models are in one place;
2. There is a possibility to run two separates `nodes` - based on needs.
3. Your development settings should be able to run dev server as a `whole`. Combing the settings from front and rest.
4. There is a clear code separation - and we know what is what in above structure.

If you have any more question - please ask.

Also I am curious what the others have to say - and how they handle issues pointed by me :)

Happy coding!